# Does Quotienting out by the Deck Transformations Give a Covering?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p:Y\to X$ be a (surjective) covering map and $G$ be the group of deck transformations of this cover. Assume $Y$ is connected. And assume, if needed, for niceness that $X$ admits a universal cover.

It is well-known that the natural projection $\pi:Y\to Y/G$ is a covering.
Here is the proof. Write $G$ to denote the set of all the deck transformations of $p:Y\to X$.
We will show that 
$$
\forall y\in Y,\exists \text{ a neighborhood } V \text{ of } y \text{ in } Y \text{ such that } V\cap gV\neq \emptyset \text{ if and only if } g \text{ is identity. }
$$
This is enough to show that $Y\to Y/G$ is a covering.
To do this, let $x=p(y)$ and $U$ be an evenly covered neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Let $V$ be the slice of $p^{-1}(U)$ contaning $y$. Suppose $V\cap gV\neq\emptyset$ for some $g\in G$.
Note that by definition of a deck transformation it follows that $gV$ is also a slice of $p^{-1}(U)$. Two slices intersect only if they are same.
Thus $gV=V$ and so $g$ must fix $y$. But any deck transformation of a connected space which fixes a point is the identity.

But the map $p$ factors through $\pi$ to induce a map $\bar p:Y/G\to X$.

> Is this map also a covering?

Comment: Do you assume any connectedness properties for either space?  Most results require something.

Comment: Also, are you assuming that the action is proper?  Based on the, "it is well-known..."

Comment: @JohnSamples I have added the connectedness hypothesis. Also, I do not think one requires any more stipulations of the nature of the action of deck transformations. I have provided an argument for showing that $Y\to Y/\text{Deck}(p:Y\to X)$ is a covering.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That property you list is the same as proper(ly discontinuous).  Have you looked in Munkres?  He has some theorem called the 'transgression lemma' or something in the covering spaces chapter.  It is a couple of commutative diagrams regarding compositions and covering spaces.

Comment: Yes, this is true. If $H$ is the subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$ corresponding to $Y$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $N(H)/H$, and so $Y/G$ is the covering corresponding to (the conjugacy class of) the subgroup $N(H)$. You can also show this directly: if $U$ is an evenly covered nbhd in $X$, the deck transformations acts on the components of $p^{-1}(U)$. You can show $U$ is still evenly covered in $Y/G$, one component for each $G$-orbit of $p^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks. I guess basically what we are using is that "if two slices intersect then they are the same." I need local connectedness of $X$ for that but that's not such a big assumption. Anyway. Can you please formulate your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be better for you to write the answer (and also I don't really have the time until next week).